# Creating alternate keys with Visio ERD diagrams

Tags: diagrams, visio

I'm trying out Visio for the first time today, creating ERD's. Is it possible to specify alternate keys in *addition* to PK's in Visio ERD diagrams. I can't see any way to define more than one key on a table.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by creating a Unique Index on the column.

1. Click the table on design surface to select the table
2. Click *Indexes*
3. Create new index column, by default indexes are non-unique, the next step fixes this
4. In the 2nd drop-down list, select Unique Index (VISIO offer 3 types)

There should be a way to display AKn of the left hand column of the design surface, but I don't know how to do this.